# ¿Como puedo sumar el total en ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Como puedo sumar los subtotales obtenidos por un ngfor? adjunto el codigo, gracias de antemano estoy muy atascado con esto...

quisiera poder tomar los datos del subtotal y sumarlos entre si para sacar el total pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo,

```
<tbody class="col-12 " *ngFor="let product of products">

            <tr class="row m-auto">
                <td class="col">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/producto',product.id]">
                        <img class="image" src="{{url + 'product/image/' + product.image}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col font-weight-bold">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/producto',product.id]">
                        {{product.name}}
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col">{{product.price | currency:'CLP'}}</td>
                <td class="col">{{product.quantity}}</td>
                <td class="col">{{product.price * product.quantity | currency:'CLP'}}</td>
            </tr>

            
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <div >Total</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te compliques intentando hacerlo en el ngFor, lo normal es calcular esa información en el componente, algo como:

```
getProducts(...) {

  this.products = ...;
  this.total = this.products.reduce((acc, product) => acc + (product.price * product.quantity));
}
```

y así muestras el valor de `total`:

```
<div >Total: {{total}}</div>
```